# Tracing route handling in mvc? (Alternatives to Glimpse?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Using VS2008/ASP.Net 3.5 i can't use Glimpse, but it would be very helpful if I could trace the route handling done by MVC some way.

Route debugger/RouteMagic seems to be ASP.Net 4 too.

I'm satisfied if I can get route/controller/view info to show up in DebugView.
How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

old version of routedebugger is available for those running .NET 3.5. visit [haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx) for detail

Comment: I've only found the nuget package. Isn't nuget VS2010 only?

Comment: from TFA: "The RouteDebugger NuGet package includes the older version of RouteDebug.dll for those still running against .NET 3.5."

Comment: @dave thieben Maybe a daft question, but how do I nuGet without VS2010? TFA? Trans fatty acid? Tenant Farmers Association?

Comment: @Carl u can find routedebugger binary at http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx. it also includes the source code you can change and compile it with 3.5 if it is in .net 4.0.

Comment: I've downloaded nuget console, and then nuget install routedebugger into an empty folder but sadly only the 4-version dll was included. LOL, nuget's a good idea in general but this reminds me of installing the Service Trace Viewer...

Comment: u can check the link i have provided. it also describes in detail how to use it with your app